# Where is this kind of pictures originated from?

Tags: anime-production, culture

The following kind of pictures has always reminded me of religion. I don't know whether they are meant to arouse such feeling, though. Where are they originated from? What is the meaning of such kind of pictures?

By the way, I can't understand the words in the pictures.

The one from the op of *Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood*(see: the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOySnqYk4EE)):[image]

The one from the op of *Neon Genesis Evangelion*:
[image]